# Percentage image prediction in Keras

Tags: python, image, keras, prediction

By this code I get single image prediction only to one class.
`classes = model.predict(images)`
`print(classes)`
result: [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Is it possible to get percentage prediction to each classes and for example get top 5 classes?

**Yes, I can share model - edit 11.05.2018**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3),  input_shape=(32, 32,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_batches,steps_per_epoch=140,validation_data=valid_batches,validation_steps=40,epochs=1000,verbose=2)
model.save_weights('weights.h5')
```

Making prediction to test dataset

```
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=20, verbose=0)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
       [6.6144131e-16, 0.0000000e+00, 1.4948792e-07, ..., 8.4376645e-15,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
       ...,
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.8744760e-06, ..., 0.0000000e+00,
        0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)
```

And my single image prediction

```
img = image.load_img('C:/Users/Kinga/Desktop/user_test/2.jpg', target_size=(32, 32))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images)
print(classes)

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: what code is generating this result? You absolutely should be getting a probability. What is your final layer like? Do you have a softmax?

Comment: Yes I have softmax. Last layer is model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Activation("softmax")) I have 20 classes

Comment: Do you have any merge layers, in particular `keras.layers.Maximum()` ?

Comment: No i don't have merge layers

Comment: Is it possible to get instead of [0.0.0.1....] probality to each class [0.99,0.77,0.5,....]?

Comment: that is what I would expect the output to be, in the absence of a maximum layer. My only other guess is the input data, training, or initialization are broken somehow.

Comment: It is an interesting question. After a bit of research, it seems that other people has similar [problems](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3173) as well. However, not everybody. Are you sure your model is not crazily overfitting?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `predict` instead of `predict_classes`? I can't imagine why your `predict` would output exact results.

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: In the top I have added my model.

Comment: From your comment "... probality to each class [0.99,0.77,0.5,....]", didn't you mean to use a sigmoid activation?

Comment: But in my model I have 20 classes, sigmoid is usually used for 2 classes model. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, the problem was in structure of my model. When I moderate it I get array with percentage probabilities.